# How to define variable in the script webpack

Tags: webpack

I need to define global variable for js on the html.
I have this config for webpack, and I am using `DefinePlugin` for this issue but it does not work.

In the webpack.config.js:

```
    plugins: [
         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
             CUSTOMER_ID:'345345e34435344'
         })
    ]
```

In the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
<head>
  <base href="/"><!-- Required for HTML5 -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(CUSTOMER_ID); // undefined
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

> plugins: [
>            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
>                CUSTOMER_ID:JSON.stringify("345345e34435344")
>            })
>       ]